# Pull text, with unique preceding text, but without a unique class or tag from webpage

Tags: html, vba, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to pull one unique number from each of a set of similar webpages. They are all very similar, but the current code I'm using uses MSXML2.XMLHTTP and identifies the text in a given class or tag.

The problem is these webpages vary slightly, so the code can't reliably pull from all of them based on an Item criteria. And, there are many of the same classes and tags on the page so there is nothing unique to identify.

However, there is a unique piece of text ("ISIN Code:"), and then ISIN number I want follows in the next line. I have heard of parsing by Ids but can't find these/don't know how this approach works.

The piece of information I want to pull is the "GB00B6Y7NF43":

```
<tr>
    <th class="align-left">ISIN code:</th>
    <td> GB00B6Y7NF43 </td>
</tr>
```

This is most of the code I am using right now to locate some other information on the page using the Item(...) approach. I don't know if my code is quite right in itself but so far it correctly pulls the information if you specify by Item(0) or Item(1) etc.

```
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim td As Object
Dim website As String
Dim charge As Variant

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

website = Range("A14").Value

End With

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

request.Open "GET", website, False

request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

html.body.innerHTML = response

Worksheets("Information").Activate

        r = r + 2:
        Cells(r, 3) = html.getElementsByClassName("header-row").Item(0).innerText
        Cells(r, 5) = html.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(0).innerText
        Cells(r, 4) = html.getElementsByClassName("icon-link pdf-icon").Item(1).href
```

Is there another approach/coding style/tweak to my code to do this?

I could use dim ie / appIe and similar methods but these have been trickier so far and slower on the pc than simply working through html text.

Comment: Can you share the website URL? The general approach, would be to find the table element, then probably just iterate every element in there looking at the InnerText.  Then selecting the next element when you find a match. There may be a more refined method, depending on the source of the page.

Comment: Please provide the url if possible so we can test.

Comment: @RyanWildry https://www.hl.co.uk/funds/fund-discounts,-prices--and--factsheets/search-results/f/fidelity-asia-class-w-accumulation/key-features thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the last child in the table so you can chain `lastchild` calls

```
html.querySelector("[summary='More fund information']").children(0).lastchild.lastchild.innertext
```

So

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.hl.co.uk/funds/fund-discounts,-prices--and--factsheets/search-results/f/fidelity-asia-class-w-accumulation/key-features", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Debug.Print html.querySelector("[summary='More fund information'] ").Children(0).LastChild.LastChild.innerText
End Sub
```

---

A slower but possibly more robust over time method might be to gather the table headers and find the one with the desired ISIN text then take the `NextSibling` (td) node.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.hl.co.uk/funds/fund-discounts,-prices--and--factsheets/search-results/f/fidelity-asia-class-w-accumulation/key-features", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim i As Long, nodes As Object

    Set nodes = html.querySelectorAll("[summary='More fund information'] th")
    For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
        If nodes.Item(i).innerText = "ISIN code:" Then
            Debug.Print nodes.Item(i).NextSibling.innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a dream mate. Thank you for the help. Good way to think about it